# Retrieving specific articles from Microsoft Academic Graph's updated API

Tags: python, get

Please note - this is *not* a duplicate question as the MAG API has been updated recently.

I am trying to do what should be a very straightforward MAG query using Python. I am using the evaluate api and the account / key is configured correctly.

Example - searching by title, works when tried using the online console [here](https://msr-apis.portal.azure-api.net/docs/services/academic-search-api/operations/565d753be597ed16ac3ffc03?)

Screen shot of console :[image]

I am aware that the search string for titles must be lowercase, all punctuation removed. So the correct formatting is Ti='this is the title'

This works perfectly in the console.

In Python however I cannot see how to add the 'Ti=this is the title' as the 'expr' part of the GET expression. I have tried this as one of the parameters and it does not seem to work.

Code from MAG site:

```
import httplib, urllib, base64

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '{subscription key}',
}

params = urllib.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'model': 'latest',
    'count': '10',
    'offset': '0',
    'orderby': '{string}',
    'attributes': 'Id',
})

try:
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("GET", "/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr={expr}&%s" % params, "{body}", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
```

I suspect I have something tiny in the wrong place. All pointers gratefully received as this is causing a certain amount of frustration now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works. I have put inline comments below so that you can easily spot the differences as compared to the original code.

```
########### Python 2.7 #############
import httplib, urllib, base64

headers = {
    # Request headers
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '{subscription key}',  # Put your key here. This should look something like: 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '3b45....'
}

# I removed the `'orderby': '{string}',` field as I didn't check what values it could take. You can look for this and other parameters which may be relevant to you.
params = urllib.urlencode({
    # Request parameters
    'model': 'latest',
    'count': '10',
    'offset': '0',
    'attributes': 'Id',
})

# define your 'exp' here. I am calling it 'my_exp'. Note that the title's value  should all be in lowercase. The urllib.quote() is needed to ensure that the spaces between words are proprely url encoded before sending to the API server. 
my_exp = urllib.quote("Ti='imagenet classification with deep convolutional neural networks'")  # an example title

try:
    conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('api.labs.cognitive.microsoft.com')
    conn.request("GET", "/academic/v1.0/evaluate?expr=%s&%s" % (my_exp,params), "", headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    data = response.read()
    print(data)
    conn.close()
except Exception as e:
    print("[Errno {0}] {1}".format(e.errno, e.strerror))
# Voila!
```